# Eevee Shader not showing in final render

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine

So i've tried to render this animation a couple of times, but in the final result it doesn't show the colors of the Sky(Plane) like it does on the sun. I used the same shader on both objects, just with other colors.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u0f0i5NZXxUbIkHjgmLmKPWjTaXAe_z9?usp=sharing
I hope that this link works.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I tried it in Cycles and have the same problem as with Eevee. I also have added some renderresults to the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the particle system that is applied to the plane you need to check "Show Emitter" in the render tab.

Comment: Thaks a lot now it worked.